# Are there significant differences between PHP 5.2 and 7+ regarding json_decode?

Tags: php

Development server is running PHP7.2, on OS X Mojave. Production server is running OS X 10.5 and PHP5.2. The obvious solution of not using a machine, OS or PHP version aren't an option.

The code is dead-simple:

```
$f = fopen("$path/to/file.csv", "w+");
    $data = json_decode($data, true);
    $header = false;
    foreach ($data as $row)
    {
        if (empty($header))
        {
            $header = array_keys($row);
            fputcsv($f, $header);
            $header = array_flip($header);
        }
        fputcsv($f, array_merge($header, $row));
    }
    fclose($f);
```

And works fine on the development machine. On the production server, however, I get `Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach` *and* `var_dump` on `$data` produces nothing.

Can anyone account for this?

*And*, PHP5.2 hasn't yet implemented json_last_error() (I'm assuming;  function-doesnt-exist error thrown when attempted)

Comment: Use `json_last_error()` to find out what the JSON problem is.

Comment: Why on _earth_ is your prod server running a PHP version from almost 15 years ago?? At the very least start working on moving that onto 5.6.40 so you're only a year and a half out of date. Having said that, don't try to find differences: if prod is (incredibly) 5.2, use 5.2 locally. But I'll let Zend say this best: ["Support for PHP 5 has been **discontinued** since **10 Jan 2019**. Please consider upgrading to 7"](https://www.php.net/releases/index.php#7.0.0), emphasis theirs, not mine. Your production server is a giant security hole just waiting to be exploited right now.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I tried that; the function didn't exist in that version of PHP.

Comment: Anyone asking about a known insecure version of PHP is going to be told this by anyone with enough PHP experience to know how disastrous this could be. If you are willing to take that risk: that's your call, but this is a 15 year old PHP version from a main line that is no longer supported in any way: you should know that, because you might not, and your post did not in any way make it clear you are aware of this, and are okay with that. So I am behaving exactly as someone you're asking for help with an ancient, highly insecure version of PHP should be on SO.

Comment: Try to `var_dump($data);` before your json_decode (so it's not overwritten), and test the output in a site such as jsonlint.com . That will tell you what is wrong with your json.

Comment: PHP 5.2 is _inexcusably_ out of date, that's your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't actually help you solve your specific problem, as there's no JSON available to reproduce it.  We can however answer your question about what differences there are.  It's right in the documentation.

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php:

```
7.3.0   JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR options was added.
7.2.0   JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE, and JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE options were added.
7.1.0   An empty JSON key ("") can be encoded to the empty object property instead of using a key with value _empty_.
7.0.0   Rejected RFC 7159 incompatible number formats - top level (07, 0xff, .1, -.1) and all levels ([1.], [1.e1])
7.0.0   An empty PHP string or value that after casting to string is an empty string (NULL, FALSE) results in JSON syntax error.
5.6.0   Invalid non-lowercased variants of the true, false and null literals are no longer accepted as valid input, and will generate warnings.
5.4.0   JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING, and JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY options were added.
5.4.0   The options parameter was added.
5.3.0   Added the optional depth. The default recursion depth was increased from 128 to 512
5.2.3   The nesting limit was increased from 20 to 128
5.2.1   Added support for JSON decoding of basic types.
```

In general, if you're using standard JSON, none of this should bite you.  There's probably something non-standard or invalid about your data.

Comment: This is the answer; ugly, inelegant, yes, but the correct one and thank you.